# Targeting Parent element of an input:checked in CSS without using has()

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, css-selectors

I am kinda stack on a task. My solution is built in Vue. I have multiple variations of a checkbox that I use with class modifiers that are applied through props. This checkbox has a wrapper (check code below). When the input is checked I want to style this wrapper, but I can't because it is the parent div:

```
  <checkbox component here>
       <div wrapper-here>
          <input:checked inside the checkbox component
```

I know there is this has() operator, but it doesn't have a super wide browser compatibility which I really need.

A solution could be to have a class modifier, that is applied to the wrapper if the checkbox is checked. But I don't wanna follow this approach for a variety of reasons. Also, I don't want to involve JQuery or any other library/ technology.

Is there **any only CSS solution** to this problem?

Comment: I don't think there is. That's why we have `:has` now (almost). There are games you can play with hidden checkboxes and labels separated from the checkboxes, but they're awkward.

Comment: If you're already using Vue, though, since there isn't (I'm pretty sure) a CSS-only solution, it's simple enough to add a class to the wrapper as needed.

Comment: Yeah, I think I will probably go with the additional modifier that adds a classname if the checkbox is the variant I need it to be & also checked. It is a little sad that :has doesnt have broad compatibility yet. But I hope they will add it in the near future.

Comment: Of major non-dead browsers, it's mostly just Firefox that's still missing it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility And Firefox for desktop does have it behind a flag, so it's en route...